# KeyBinding.Keyvalue="F6" Cant i read this value from resource File c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to read the value like this `<KeyBinding Key="{x:Static prop:Resources.F6}"`
it gives me an error Invalid type. It works when it is `<KeyBinding Key="F6"`

Any ideas or reason for this is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.input.keybinding.key.aspx) states, the `KeyBinding.Key` property is of the enum type `Key`. WPF will convert the string "F6" to Key.F6. Unless your `Resources.F6` property also returns a `Key` enumeration, this will not work.